# Error While testing oneM2M Device Simulator with Mobius API

Tags: iot, onem2m

please help me with below error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBRT1.png)

I am trying to connect onem2m device simulator to mobius API.

Comment: Please add errors and codes as text in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Could you please post a longer log in your question? Otherwise one cannot determine the cause of an error.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with Mobius, it appears to me that the *releaseVersionIndicator* parameter is missing from your request primitive.

To get this far, you have probably sent other primitives that do include the *releaseVersionIndicator* (rvi).  So you can probably refer to other examples in your own project for how to include it.

Bob